# Linksys E1200 Gateway

Tags: router, ip, gateway

I received static ip data from the provider. It's like this:

```
ip: x.x.x.1/31 
sub: 255.255.255.254
gateway: x.x.x.0/31
DNS: x.x.x.x and x.x.x.x
```

When I try to enter the gateway in linksys E1200, it doesn't accept number "0". It shows an error and tell me that I have to use number from 1 to 254.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image: See The Image Here]]

Comment: Normal, you normally can't configure a x.y.z.0 in a consumer router and it's rare. But [Server Fault.SE](https://serverfault.com/q/10985) has you covered.

Comment: @CaldeiraG: That's an unfortunate assumption on part of those routers. x.y.z.0 is possible to be valid with all netmasks shorter than /24. (And with /31 in OP's case, which is an exception to many rules.)

Comment: @grawity thanks for pointing out! I'm no expert in networking but you're indeed right, it's not a normal config with a /31 netmask.

Comment: Thank you CaldeiraG & grawity
So, What do you suggest change the router or there is a workaround?